# c# Linq Query in mvc5 is returning the column name instead of value

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am doing an assignment using MVC5, I am trying to create a query using Linq which will return the logged in users "StudentId" from the "AspNetUsers" table. The code I have to try do this is,

```
string currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            string getStudentId = (from a in db.Users
                                   where a.Id.Equals(currentUser)
                                   select a.StudentId).ToString();
```

This is setting the string value to "StudentId;" which is the name of the column. (The ID is the default AspNetUsers table Data type which is nvarchar(128) ). Any help on where I am going wrong is much appreciated.

Comment: Your query returns a collection of `StudentId`, not a single item. You need `.FirstOrDefault()` before calling `.ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to execute the query first:

```
string getStudentId = (from a in db.Users
                               where a.Id.Equals(currentUser)
                               select a.StudentId).First().ToString();
```

Comment: I already tried the code you suggested and it still returns the column name.

Comment: Is "StudentId" a table in the database or a column in the Users table?

Comment: it is A column in Users table

Comment: Strange, I've tried it here on one of my databases and it works as expected. Are you sure "StudentId;" is not actually the value in the database?

Answer (score 0):

One solution Might be

```
string currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
string studentId;
studentId=db.Users.SingleOrDefault(o=>o.Id==currentUser).Select(o=>o.StudentId.ToString());
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, I got an error saying there is no value for select in applicationUser

Comment: The correct syntax in this case would be:
studentId=db.Users.SingleOrDefault(o=>o.Id==currentUser).StudentId.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with minor modifications below:
(I substituted your StudentId column with my UserName column, and the viewbag shows the correct UserName on the view page)

```
        string currentUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var getStudentId = (from a in db.Users
                               where a.Id.Equals(currentUser)
                               select a.UserName).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

        ViewBag.TestUser = getStudentId;
```

[ Update ]

I am assuming that your StudentId column is in your Users table.